# JPA Meta model - Best practices

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven, jpa

I just configured Maven to generate my Hibernate JPA meta-model but now I'm in doubt about how to manage it. What is the best practices to work with meta-model class?

1. Generate it in src folder
2. Keep it in `target/generated-sources/annotations` (Maven does it automatically)

If #2 is best choice, how do I add it to Eclipse build path when I import Maven project? I'd like to do it automatically, without the need to configure each project.

**Update(21/06/2016)**

Based on Michele's advice, I updated and found a working solution.

1) To generate Meta model, just add this dependence to :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

2) Add this plugin to pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>add-source</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations/</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Stick with `target/generated-sources/annotations` or you'll regret it for thousands of reasons. I do not import projects frequently (I just create them on eclipse), but IIRC m2e-wtp plugin auto adds that folder to the build path.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your advice, I'll keep it. Based on what you said, I updated my question, case anyone else needs this info. Only difference I'm using another plugin build-helper-maven-plugin from org.codehaus.mojo. See my updated question.